# Why does postfix use manual section 1 and not 8?

Tags: linux, postfix, man

I am trying to better understand the Linux's online manual.  I thought I understood it, but then came across this.  Why is postfix under User Commands (1) and not System Administration tools and Daemons (8)?

```
[Michael@devserver postfix]$ man man
MANUAL SECTIONS
       The standard sections of the manual include:
       1      User Commands
              ...
       8      System Administration tools and Daemons
```

.

```
[Michael@devserver postfix]$ man postfix
POSTFIX(1)

NAME
       postfix - Postfix control program

SYNOPSIS
       postfix [-Dv] [-c config_dir] command

DESCRIPTION
       This command is reserved for the superuser. To submit mail, use the Postfix sendmail(1) command.

       The postfix(1) command controls the operation of the Postfix mail system: start or stop the master(8) daemon, do a health check, and other maintenance.
```

Comment: I suspect it started out with some user-facing functionality, and now moving it to a different man page section is a lot of hassle for very little benefit.

Comment: @tripleee  Thanks.  Good to know that I am not along, and if it was created today, should have been (8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Postfix mail system includes a host of commands and daemons, not just the `postfix` command.

It appears that the authors of Postfix has decided that user-accessible commands should be in section 1, no matter if they are for system administration purposes or not:

- postalias(1), create/update/query alias database
- postcat(1), examine Postfix queue file
- postconf(1), Postfix configuration utility
- postfix(1), Postfix control program
- postfix-tls(1), Postfix TLS management
- postkick(1), trigger Postfix daemon
- postlock(1), Postfix-compatible locking
- postlog(1), Postfix-compatible logging
- postmap(1), Postfix lookup table manager
- postmulti(1), Postfix multi-instance manager
- postqueue(1), Postfix mail queue control
- postsuper(1), Postfix housekeeping
- mailq(1), Sendmail compatibility interface
- newaliases(1), Sendmail compatibility interface
- sendmail(1), Sendmail compatibility interface

In section 8, you'll find only daemons, i.e. things you're not supposed to run manually:

- anvil(8), Postfix connection/rate limiting
- bounce(8), defer(8), trace(8), Delivery status reports
- cleanup(8), canonicalize and enqueue message
- discard(8), Postfix discard delivery agent
- dnsblog(8), DNS black/whitelist logger
- error(8), Postfix error delivery agent
- (etc. etc.)

There are also manuals in section 5 ("file formats").

Their rationale for this is

> Each Postfix manual page is numbered after a section of the UNIX manual: examples are mailq(1) or access(5). Unfortunately, there is no single universal method to organize manual pages; each UNIX flavor appears to be different.

See [all Postfix manuals](http://www.postfix.org/postfix-manuals.html) for further information.